# Cakephp: How to add variable value to table

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers

How can I add a variable value to table with cakephp formhelper. In my form, I allow user to input some values, but the user's ip address also add to table. I also calculate user's input before insert into database.

Should I modify controller or model in cakephp. I have a Number table with id, cybernumber, created, department, ipaddress. Thanks very much.

```
//Controller/NumberController.php
public function add() 
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $this->Number->create();
        //not working 
        //$this->request->data['Number']['ipaddress'] = $this->request->clientIp();
        //not working 
        //$this->Number->set('ipaddress',$this->request->clientIp());

        if ($this->Number->save($this->request->data)) 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('OK.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
}

// Model/Number.php
<?php

class Number extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'cybernumber' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'unique only'
        ),
        'department' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First in Config/core.php change: Configure::write('debug', 0); to Configure::write('debug', 1);

After

```
$this->Number->create();
$this->request->data['Number']['ipaddress'] = $this->request->clientIp();
```

Add

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

Check if the `ipaddress` field is there.

Try to check the type of field in your database. Maybe it is incompatible with the format of data.